# How to start a psql command line?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, psql

I'm trying to create a postgresql user and password. [This tutorial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-createuser.html) supplies the command to create a user, but I can't find anywhere how to actually start the psql command line, where I would then run the `CREATE USER` command.

How can I start a psql command line? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

I tried just running `psql`, but I get back

```
psql: FATAL:  role "user" does not exist
```

But I can't create a user without logging into the command line...

Comment: @zerkms That was my intuition, but it doesn't work.

Comment: `sudo -u postgres psql`

Comment: @zerkms Ah great, thank you! If you post as an answer I can accept it :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`psql` if run by default without any arguments takes the current user name which obviously does not exist, since you just installed a postgresql.

From the other hand ubuntu's postgresql distribution comes with a default `postgres` user created (both in system and in postgresql databse). Which means that if you run a `psql` command on behalf of a `postgres` user then you would be able to connect:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```